# Trying to figure out how to count this measure!

Tags: theory

I'm trying to get through measure 4 of the passage in the image below:

[image: An image of a question about a Mozart passage in a PDF title "HASOM Piano Assessment Instructions"]

The relevant parts:

```
X:1
C: W.A. Mozart
T: Andante
M: 3/4
L: 1/8
K: A
( !mp! c3 d c2 | e4 ) ( e2 | !p! B3 c B2 | d4 ) d2 |
```

Can you count the first two measures with the beats?  I think I'm blanking, but when I count, on the dotted quarter note I go "one (and)", the eighth note is "two", and the last quarter note is "three", but that doesn't sound right because the eighth note doesn't go from "two" to "three".

Comment: A side note that might actually make things more confusing. This kind of melody is inviting (to me) to be counted on 1 and 3. It gives the melody a different "swing" from counting straight 3 when you emphasize the 1 and 3 in the bar, sort of more dance like. The 3/4 time signature is a bit special as it often referrs to dances used in social contexts. A further example  can be viennese waltz that has and uneven count on 3 -- the first count is longer than 2 and 3. This difference in how the music is written to how it is performed is perhaps most noticeable in swing or jazz music.

Answer (score 11):

Here's one more answer, using some notation. You would count like this—making sure, even though I've kind of bunched up the numbers and "&"s here, that you make them all equal in duration:

[image]

This is because the dotted quarter is actually a quarter note plus an eighth note, like this:

[image]

Also because, when you say a number like "two," that isn't "all" of the beat, just the beginning of it. So the beginning of beat two is part of the C#, but the rest of beat two is the D eighth note.

Answer (score 7):

When I was learning, I'd often split the bars into smaller portions. So here, with 3 main beats per bar, I'd split i t into 6. Then the count's easy. 123 on the 1st note, 4 on the next, and 56 on the last in bar 1.

Counting with 'and' didn't work too well, as I'd often forget which numbers the 'and' came between!

Comment: The "and" comes between all the numbers.  That should be easy to remember!  +1, but those following this advice should be careful to count *1* 2 *3* 4 *5* 6 instead of *1* 2 3 *4* 5 6, which is the standard way to count 6/8 (or one of them, at least, when the tempo is slow to moderate).

Comment: Well, nothing wrong with counting your beats "eenie meenie miney" or "oh my stars and garters". Any phrase with the right rhythm will do.

Comment: In my previous comment I meant to use boldface rather than italic, that is "should be careful to count **1** 2 **3** 4 **5** 6 instead of **1** 2 3 **4** 5 6."

Comment: @phoog - good point, but in this instance, it'll make no difference at all!

Answer (score 5):

> when I count, on the dotted quarter note I go "one (and)", the eighth note is "two", and the last quarter note is "three"

You started off right!  The first note comes on 'one'.  And you've got the idea of subdividing the 'One, two, three' count with 'and'.   But you've misplaced 'two'.  That dotted quarter extends beyond 'two'.  The 8th doesn't come until the 'and' after 'two'.   It's 'one, two-AND'.   Then the last quarter firmly on 'three'.   The whole bar goes 'One (and) (two) AND THREE (and).

You know this rhythm.'Sil-ent Night...'   Got it?

Comment: Very good song reference for this rhythm!

Comment: Couldn't find a better example! Well done. +1. Although is that carol in 3/4 or 6/8..?

Comment: @Tim Doesn't matter how Silent Night is notated, that's the rhythm!

Answer (score 4):

You're counting the eighth early. Keep in mind that a dotted note is longer than its undotted sibling (by half of the base duration) - a dotted quarter is 3/8 long.

The dotted quarter takes one and a half of a beat, the eighth takes the second half of the second beat, and the quarter takes the third beat; in the second measure, the half takes the first and second beat and the quarter takes the third beat.

Counting (slash = next note):

> one-and two-/-and / three-and /
> one-and two-and / three-and

The whole point of notes being eighths and quarters and dotted quarters and halves is that their duration differs.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers have explained how to count this with six counts in the measure, one for each eight note.  This is a good technique for learning, but you probably should keep sight of the ultimate goal -- or at least return to it eventually -- which is to count with three beats to the measure.  In that case, the eighth note *doesn't coincide with any count at all*; it comes midway between *2* and *3*:

```
Right hand C♯.......D..C♯....E...........E.....B........C♯.B.....D (etc.)
Voice      1.....2.....3.....1.....2.....3.....1.....2.....3.....1 (etc.)
```

Comment: And here I was thinking the ultimate goal should be to play without counting...

Comment: @Divizna well, ok, yes.  But even if I'm not counting out loud there's some metrical something going on silently in my head, and that normally corresponds to quarter notes in 3/4 at this tempo rather than eighth notes.  Not always, but normally.

Comment: @Divizna - playing and counting go hand in hand. I remember playing a new number with a big band, and all the conductor said was 'heads down and count like hell' - and we were all seasoned players. There's often no other way to get things right!

Comment: In trying to match what would really go on in my head to the approach OP seems to want to be taking (actually verbalising numbers corresponding to position in the bar) I came up with counting "One two-and three", which kind of splits the difference between this answer and the six-count approach

Comment: Plus one to this sentiment, though it's most likely something the OP isn't ready for. If they're not clear how dots work, they probably need a very metronomic focus on beats and subdivisions at first; the next scaffolded skill is to "erase" the subdivisions, and really the next should be to erase beats 2 and 3 as well and count it "in 1." (And the next after that should be phrasing, such that "the ones" themselves fall into a hierarchy.) But those attainments pretty much have to come in that order; there's a reason that beginners' performances are often so strongly pulsed.

Comment: @Tim To each their own. Reciting the numbers has always been downright counterproductive for me. My subconscious is way better at this than my conscious, and to invest verbal effort? I suppose I could do "duda duda duda" if I needed (not that I ever have), but "oneand twoand threeand" leeches on my cognitive capacity needed elsewhere. Luckily the last time someone demanded that of me was when I was six. Mostly, I "count" with my hand as I'm strumming the chords. (Except not really because I vary the strumming pattern for expression.)

Comment: The ideal is to recognise and internalise any rhythmic pattern you're likely to encounter.   But I doubt there's many of us who didn't  pencil in the beats when we first encountered a piece of Messiaen, or the first time  Nestico's 'Ya Gotta Try' hit the stand!    (It's great being a trombonist, you get to play both!)